# What source code files should be included in version control for Ionic2 application?

Tags: version-control, ionic2, ionic3

Im building an Ionic 2 application. Version control will be made through SVN.
When creating the app using ionic CLI many files are generated. Same happens when adding platforms.

Is there any standard approach defining which files to include in Version Controls and which ones to ingnore. (I.E. i think platforms folder should be ignored).

[image: Here is the file structure of an Ionic 2 App]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always take a look at the [conference app](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app) to see how Ionic team recommends to do things. In this case the `.gitignore` file looks like this:

```
# Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore when using Git
# http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

*~
*.sw[mnpcod]
*.log
*.tmp
*.tmp.*
log.txt
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace
.vscode/
npm-debug.log*

.idea/
.sass-cache/
.tmp/
.versions/
coverage/
dist/
node_modules/
tmp/
temp/
hooks/
platforms/
plugins/
plugins/android.json
plugins/ios.json
$RECYCLE.BIN/

.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Like you can see there, the platform and the plugins folders are being ignored for example

Answer (score 0):

Common Ignores
.vscode/
.DS_Store

ionic
node_modules/
plugins/

Platform iOS
*.mode1v3
*.perspectivev3
*.pbxuser
platforms/ios/build

Platform Android
platforms/android/build.xml
platforms/android/local.properties
platforms/android/gradlew
platforms/android/gradlew.bat
platforms/android/gradle

Ant builds
platforms/android/ant-build
platforms/android/ant-gen

Eclipse builds
platforms/android/gen
platforms/android/out

Gradle builds
platforms/android/build

Check - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/.gitignore