# angular 2/ionic2/cordova what to skip source control

Tags: git, angular, cordova, ionic2

I am using ionic 2/angular 2/ cordova for my app building.
Currently my target is IOS.

I have enabled git to source control.
I am not sure from below which locations should I skip source control.
I have checked some generic answers but they are not helpful.

Some key I need to know if i can skip:

```
<my app>/platforms/ios 
<my app>/www/build
```

If there are any additional such locations do let me know please.

one place i saw like below list but seems too generic
node_modules
dist
.tmp
.sass-cache
bower_components

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What source code files should be included in version control for Ionic2 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998202/what-source-code-files-should-be-included-in-version-control-for-ionic2-applicat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the services from [**gitignore.io**](https://www.gitignore.io/), and combine the content from:
Angular and Cordova:

https://www.gitignore.io/api/angular%2Capachecordova

That will give you one `.gitignore` file that you need to create *before* your first `git add`/`git commit`.
It seems to cover what was [already recommended for an ionic project in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30330276/6309), including `platforms/*`.
I don't see `www/build/` in it, but if that folder content is generated, it should be ignored as well, as in this [`ionic-2-sample/.gitignore`](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ionic-2-sample/blob/master/.gitignore) file.
So you can add that rule `www/build/` to your .gitignore fie as well.